Issues with Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) Not Triggering as Expected on Vercel
Issue Description
I am experiencing issues with the Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) feature in my Next.js application hosted on Vercel. Despite setting the revalidate option in getStaticProps, the pages do not seem to be regenerating at the specified intervals.
Details

Framework: Next.js
Hosting: Vercel
Function: getStaticProps with revalidate set to 600 seconds (10 minutes)
Expected Behavior: The pages should regenerate every 10 minutes when accessed after the set interval.
Current Behavior: Pages remain static and do not update as expected, even when accessed after the 10-minute interval.

Steps to Reproduce

Set up a Next.js application with getStaticProps implemented.
Deploy the application to Vercel.
Access the page to trigger the initial static generation.
Modify the source content (e.g., update data in a CMS or database).
Access the page after the revalidate period has elapsed.
Observe that the changes are not reflected in the regenerated page.

Additional Information

No errors are shown in the Vercel function logs.
Environment variables and API keys are correctly configured.
The issue persists across multiple deployments and even after clearing the cache.

Expected Resolution

Clarification on whether there is a known issue with ISR on Vercel that might be affecting this functionality.
Any potential workarounds or settings that might need to be adjusted to ensure that ISR works as expected.
Assistance in debugging this issue to determine if the configuration might be incorrect or if there are other underlying problems.

Conclusion
This issue is critical as it affects the dynamic nature of my site, which relies on timely content updates. I appreciate any guidance or support that can be provided to resolve this issue promptly.
